# property of universally measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal B_d$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^d$ and define $\mathcal B_d^*= \bigcap_{\rho} \overline{\mathcal B_d}^{\rho}$, where $\overline{\mathcal B_d}^{\rho}$ is the completion of $\mathcal B_d$ w.r.t probability measure $\rho$ on $\mathbb R^d$. A function $f$ is called universally measurable if it is $\mathcal B_d^*$-measurable. What I want to check is that, given a  real-valued universally measurable function $f$ and a probability measure $\eta$ on $\mathbb R^d$, there are Borel measurable functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ such that $f_1 \le f \le f_2$ and $\int (f_2(x)-f_1(x)) \ \eta(dx) =0$. It seems like an analogue of Vitali-Caratheodory theorem, but there is no $L^1$ condition here. How can I show this?

Comment: Huh. I would have guessed that $\mathcal B_d^*=\mathcal B_d$. Is it easy to see that's not so?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Not easy, but there is an analytic set whose complement is not analytic, hence not Borel. Analytic sets are universally measurable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_theorem

Comment: Uh.. I've just had another problem :(